# How to fill IEnumerable-Property of Object using MEF and DirectoryCatalog

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, mef

What I am basically trying to achieve is to combine MEF and Castle Windsor.
But I happen to be unable to get started using MEF. The Problem is, when I call `ComposeParts` on the `compositionContainer` in the `MefInstaller`-Class, it doesn't fill the `installers`-collection, for some reason.

The `DirectoryCoatalog` words fine and loads the needed files properly (including **ModuleA.dll**).

```
public class MefInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<IWindsorInstaller> installers { get; set; }  // here the Exported Objects should be stored

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        var directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directory); 
        var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(directoryCatalog);

        compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);

        foreach (var windsorInstaller in installers)
        {
            windsorInstaller.Install(container, store);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("List in Field : {0}", installers.Count());
    }
}
```

The Class to import looks as the following:

```
[Export("ComponentInstaller")]
public class ModuleAInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container
            .Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<FooA>())
            .Register(Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<BarA>());
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I have experimented with different attributes and contract names on both the `MefInstaller` and `ModuleAInstaller`-Classes. I have also tried to compose the parts using a `CompositionBatch` with no success. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have solved it. The problem was the attribute on the `ModuleAInstaller`-Class.

everything works fine using

```
[Export(typeof(IWindsorInstaller))]
public class ModuleAInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    [...]
}
```